# Google sign-in in an Electron.js application not working

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application, google-signin

I'm making a desktop app version of a website with electron.  The desktop app itself works, but the google sign in does not work because "this browser is not secure."

Opening the sign-in page in a secure browser will not work here because i did not make the actual sign-in version itself, I am only making the desktop app version.

I've seen other posts where they say to change the userAgent, but Google has disabled that, so it will not work.

I also have used a solution with `nativefier app --userAgent...`, but the Windows and Linux versions become messy with a bunch of extra files after building.  I would like to get a single .exe file for Windows and a single .AppImage or .deb file or similar for Linux if possible.

If you have any solutions or workarounds for this, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: how are you redirecting the `google sign in` page here? Are you rendering inside Electron app or redirecting to the google authentication website?

Comment: It opens a new window in the electron app (at least it does for me).  So there's the main page, and then when you click the sign-in button, it opens a new window with the sign-in page on it.

Comment: try this: https://arunpasupathi.medium.com/how-to-implement-google-authentication-in-your-electron-app-aec168af7410

Comment: @Thinker that's not quite what I'm looking for, although it does help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to log in with Google using this package: [getstation/electron-google-oauth2](https://github.com/getstation/electron-google-oauth2). This package will open a browser window for the log in, then successfully pass it to Electron app. There are examples in the readme demonstrating how to make it work.

Also make sure that you configure a desktop OAuth 2.0 Client ID for the app:
[image: A screenshot from console.google.com, demonstrating the selection of a desktop app OAuth 2.0 Client ID]